# Como salvar o html atual de um webview do flutter após as edições do usuário

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

Estou trabalhando em um app que deverá permitir preencher laudos mesmo sem internet. A empresa tem dezenas de laudos e mudam constantemente o layout e campos. Deram a ideia de trabalhar com o HTML pois eles já tem o laudo em html para ser preenchido online.

Estou fazendo alguns testes com o webview do flutter. Já consegui setar uma string que contem o html no webview e executar javascript. Mas precisaria salvar os campos que o usuário alterou para posteriormente fazer o upload desse html.

Único código que encontrei na web é esse.

```
String html = await _controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult("window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;");
```

O problema é que retorna o html que eu setei na webview e não busca as alterações que o usuário fez. Se ele preencheu um campo tipo text. O campo continua vazio executando esse JS.
Sei que posso pelo id ou nome do campo buscar o campo em si. Testei e funcionou, mas como não sei quais são todos os campos e os tipos (text, checkbox, textarea), não sei como salvar esses dados estando offline.

Estou sem ideias. Se alguém souber como posso fazer isso usando o webview. Talvez com outros plugins.
Ou se não é possível fazer isso. Estou no início do projeto ainda da tempo de mudar de planos mas preciso avisar a equipe de programação da outra empresa caso não for possível salvar o html final gerado pelo usuário.